# Suggestions on how to deal with contamination?

Tags: contamination, racking

When I was about to leave this morning, I noticed that one of my carboys has this white mold growing on the surface.

[image]

In 8 years of homebrewing, this is the first time it happens. This is a braggot I've been aging for 6 months and I had recently racked it off to remove some sediment. I guess something got inside during that process.

I was thinking of racking it tonight and discard the head and hopefully, that could help it? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racking to secondary probably introduced the contamination.  You can try to kill the contamination by racking from under it and also adding Campden or metabisulfite chemical in the amounts recommended by the manufacturer (typically this is 1 Campden tablet per gallon, or equivalent).  Also, taste the batch -- it might already be souring or otherwise not taste very good, in which case you might want to dump it out.  Otherwise it is best if you can drink it as soon as possible before the contamination has any chance to progress any further.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: Either Campden or some dry hoping (since hop is also a preservative).  I would not age it any longer...  ymmv

Comment: I'll probably do both. I got some spare hops in my fridge so I'll add some metasulfties (I don't have any campden on hand) and a bit of dry hopping. I'll post an update tonight when it's done.

Comment: Just added both hops and sulfites and took a quick taste test. No odd flavours that I could distinguish. I'll monitor it for the next couple of days, but I'll probably bottle it up early next week and start drinking it if nothing weird shows up.